# Cat6 termination problem

Tags: cat6

After terminating Cat6 cable I plug it in to cable tester to check if every ping/pair is fine and I can use the cable. The problem I am having is that after crimping Cat6 cable with either T568A or T568B termination my tester says that there is a problem with pin 3 and 6. When I get into my office and do the same with a different cable the tester says everything is fine and the cable is working ok. Is something wrong with my outside cable or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Okay, I'm confused - what's different between inside and outside the office.  Just the cable spool you're pulling from?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I guess in the absence of anything else it almost HAS to be that, though.  Maybe one of those wires was threaded to too thin a gauge or something at the factory...try just cutting a short piece and seeing what a continuity tester has to say about those wires?

Comment: Nevermind, you tried with both specs, so using DIFFERENT cable pairs?!  Now I'm really confused.  (Unless they're the same between A and B - I don't have these memorized.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you terminate T568A and T568B and you get the same 3/6 error, then the problem is the other end. A and B swap pairs 1/2 and 3/6, so if the error is on the same pins, then the actual pairs are good but the termination point on the other end is bad. Otherwise you would see a 1/2 error when you went from B to A.

Comment: That might be it. Now I have to trace the cable. Geez

Answer (score 1):

That's not a lot to go on. Are you using the correct connector for the type of cable? (stranded vs solid? They also have combination types, but make sure you're not using the wrong one) also, 3 and 6 are stripe vs solid pairs of green or orange depending on if you're using T568A or B. Are you sure you haven't swapped them on one end? I'm guessing the fact that you get the same pin error regardless of A or B standard indicates that you're probably NOT accidentally swapping them, but it's worth checking. You may not be pressing the strands far enough into the connector before crimping or your crimp tool may be damaged at one or both of those pins. Make sure the pjns are all pressed in evenly and that none of "teeth" in the crimp die are broken and that the strands are all flush against the face of the connector.

Comment: I do press the strands into the connector evenly and far enough. I performed it several times on the outside cable and once in the office on a different cable. I am successful at crimping in my office with the same type of connector and the same crimping tool.